# Angular Material Buttons No Hover color

Tags: angular, angular-material

I recently installed Angular Material on my application.  I used the command `ng add @angular/material` and answered yes to all the questions.  Then I imported `import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';` and used the following html:

```
<button mat-button>Submit</button>
```

The button looks fine until you try to hover over it.  On the Angular Material test site, the button will change to a gray when you hover the mouse.  On my version nothing happens:
[image]

Comment: Did you also import the BrowserAnimationsModule?

Comment: yes I did, still doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

1. It might be some other CSS configurations are preventing that from happening. Custom theming?
2. Just in case, also pointing it out that hover does not work on touch devices (e.g. mobile).
3. Good idea is to restart development server `ng serve` after installation.
4. Also import `MatButtonModule, BrowserAnimationsModule` to respectful `@NgModule`.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I just had to completely uninstall all of my imports and re-install, then it worked.